# Drawing text using PdfTextArray in iTextSharp - how?

Tags: itext

I am drawing text in a PDF page using iTextSharp, and I have two requirements:
1) the text needs to be searchable by Adobe Reader and such
2) I need character-level control over where the text is drawn.

I can draw the text word-by-word using PdfContentByte.ShowText(), but I don't have control over where each character is drawn.
I can draw the text character-by-character using PdfContentByte.ShowText() but then it isn't searchable.
I'm now trying to create a PdfTextArray, which would seem to satisfy both of my requirements, but I'm having trouble calculating the correct offsets.

So my first question is: do you agree that PdfTextArray is what I need to do, in order to satisfy both of my original requirements?

If so, I have the PdfTextArray working correctly (in that it's outputting text) but I can't figure out how to accurately calculate the positioning offset that needs to get put between each pair of characters (right now I'm just using the fixed value -200 just to prove that the function works).

I believe the positioning offset is the distance from the right edge of the previous character to the left edge of the new character, expressed in "thousandths of a unit of text space".  That leaves me two problems:

1) How wide is the previous character (in points), as drawn in the specified font & height?  (I know where its left edge is, since I drew it there)

2) How do I convert from points to "units of text space"?

I'm not doing any fancy scaling or rotating, so my transformation matrices should all be identity matrices, which should simplify the calculations ...

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: What is a *point* for you? (There are multiple definitions with slightly different values.) If it is 1/72", then that's your default user space unit. So you only have to keep track of the current transformation Matrix, the text Matrix, and the other relevant text mode graphic state parameters.

Comment: Yup, I'm using the standard point = 1/72".  But that's not the unit that is used for PdfTextArray - the PDF document talks about "units of text space" which are some different beast.

Comment: The transformation from text space to default (i.e.  untransformed) user space happens by means of numerous  transformations which in turn depend on the current graphics state.

Comment: Hence my statement "I'm not doing any fancy scaling or rotating, so my transformation matrices should all be identity matrices, which should simplify the calculations ."  Also, and maybe I'm wrong about this, but I think there is a special unit set up for this - something to do with the height of the font.  I don't think it's the usual user spaces with their usual transformations.